# Proper syntax when using filter_input_array with flags and callbacks?

Tags: php

I have a form that submits an array in the name ('foo' is dynamic and not repeated) like so
`name="formLink['foo']`

I use filter_input_array to filter and use a custom callback that checks the length of the array value. The issue is the flags ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY and ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH do not do anything.

```
$filters = array(
    "formLink" => array("filter" => FILTER_CALLBACK,
    "flags" => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY | ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY,
    "options" => "Validation::validLength"
)
$arr = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filters);

public static function validLength($str) {
    if (strlen($str) > 30) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Value of `$arr` is

```
array(1) (
    [formLink] => array(1) (
    [foo] => (bool) true
)
```

I'm not sure why the array value is being changed to boolean when I thought if you return true it simply keeps the value and when returning false removes the value.

I have tried removing the other filters and rearranging the position of the flags to no avail. I also have tried a function with 2 arguments to work with ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH expecting 2 arguments but it never sends both arguments.

According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.misc.php all flags are ignored when using FILTER_CALLBACK, which I find strange as flags work with array_filter callbacks- array_filter ($array, call_back_function(),$flag); I guess that is the answer to why the flags aren't working. So the remaining question is why is the callback changing the array value?

*edit:
I see that I can return the same string but I thought it was supposed to work as I mentioned, also still trying to send array key as well as value.

*edit:
This example uses the FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY flag with FILTER_CALLBACK, https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_input_array.asp

Comment: Note: An array cannot have several keys with same name.

Comment: Sorry the keys are actually dynamic let me edit the post quick.

Comment: My comment was about the `flags` and `options` keys in `$filters['formLink']['filter']`. Seems that some code is missing. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok thanks it should be good now.

Comment: I suggest you do some reading on this topic and then edit your question into coherence. It appears you are asking 2 questions here – why the flags aren't working and why the value changes. It also appears that you have the answers to these in your question – "according to [the documentation] all flags are ignored when using `FILTER_CALLBACK`" and "I see that I can return the same string." So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @miken32 there are still 2 unanswered parts to the post. Returning true should leave the array alone and not modify it, so why is it modifying the array? "I am still trying to send the array key". How do I send the array key?